# Multiple Fetching from different rows in one loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for my bad English.

So this is my table in the database.

```
 course - lecturer - time
 CSS --- John --- 8:00 AM, 2016/01/21, Sunday
 CSS --- John --- 10:00 AM, 2016/01/23, Tuesday
 CSS --- John --- 1:00 PM, 2016/01/25, Thursday
 HTML --- Ben --- 10:00 AM, 2016/01/22, Monday
 HTML --- Ben --- 8:00 AM, 2016/01/23, Tuesday
```

As you can see, the Courses and Lecturers are duplicated but the time is different in different rows. Everytime I try to fetch from database and view to html page, it creates a table for each row, which is stupid and not professional.

I want the output to be like this :

```html
    <table border=2>
        <tr>
            <td> course name :  </td> <td colspan=3> css </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> lecturer :  </td> <td colspan=3> John </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> time :  </td> <td> 8:00 AM, 2016/01/21, Sunday </td> <td> 10:00 AM, 2016/01/23, Tuesday </td> <td> 1:00 PM, 2016/01/25, Thursday </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I tried but I just realized I'm not good enough with PHP.

This is my original PHP code...

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM courses";
$results=mysql_query($qry);
if($results)
{
if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0)
{
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
echo "<center><table width=400 border=1>
<tr><td><b> Course Name : </b></td><td>". $rows["course"]."</td></tr>
<tr><td><b> Lecturer Name : </b></td><td>". $rows["lecturer"]."</td></tr>
<tr><td><b> Time : </b></td><td>". $rows["time"]."</td></tr>
</center></table><br>";
}
}
else {echo "<center>not available</center>";}
}
```

Sorry if I bothered.

Comment: include .php file between <table> </table>

Comment: Please be aware that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are obsolete -- you are strongly recommended to switch to using the newer `mysqli_xxx()` functions or the PDO library. Also note that the old functions are being removed in the next version of PHP, so if you keep your code as it is, you will not be able to upgrade, or your software may stop working if your web host upgrades.

Comment: @ChiragSenjaliya I don't think that's gonna work. I tried it. And it never did.

Comment: @Simba I'm aware of that. This is me only practicing PHP for my future . Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Fair enough. But if I was trying to learn a language or practice it, I'd make a point of learning the up-to-date bits and not the obsolete bits. Just saying.  :)

Comment: @Simba I totally agree. But this is for a college project, and I've learned the old codes on an old version of WampServer. If I change codes I will be confused. If you have a link or two for what has changed and how to use after change, that would be nice.

Comment: What version of PHP is your wampserver running? A whole lot has changed in the language over the last few years. But more importantly, there's much more emphasis on writing good quality code. The difference in style of PHP tutorials from today and 10 years ago is enormous, and much more than just what has changed in the language. I suggest a good starting point would be http://phptherightway.com/ but more generally, if a tutorial was written more than a three of four years ago, you should consider it obsolete.

Comment: By the way, the features that have been removed from PHP over time are mostly the ones which have caused major security problems for PHP sites (magic quotes, the old mysql functions, etc). The features which have been added are mostly ones which help you to structure your code better (object oriented features, namespaces, etc).

Comment: @Simba I use WampServer 2.2d, so I don't know what version of PHP it uses. I know, I once tried to use the new PHP coding with old codes, I got so confused, I had to to revert to the old one. lol. Thanks for the help. You've been nothing but helpful. Thank you my friend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92480/discussion-between-simba-and-nizar).

Comment: for ref, it looks like WampServer 2.2 is using PHP 5.4, which is old, but not too bad. Current version of PHP is 5.6 (WampServer v2.5). But also note that PHP v7 is due out next month with lots of big changes.

Comment: v6... heh, that's a very long story. Some background here https://ma.ttias.be/php6-missing-version-number/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace :

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM courses";
$results=mysql_query($qry);
if($results)
{
if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0)
{
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
echo "<center><table width=400 border=1>
<tr><td><b> Course Name : </b></td><td>". $rows["course"]."</td></tr>
<tr><td><b> Lecturer Name : </b></td><td>". $rows["lecturer"]."</td></tr>
<tr><td><b> Time : </b></td><td>". $rows["time"]."</td></tr>
</center></table><br>";
}
}
else {echo "<center>not available</center>";}
}
```

with

```
$qry="SELECT distinct course as c, (SELECT lecturer from courses where course=c limit 1) as l FROM courses";
$results=mysql_query($qry);
if($results)
{
if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0)
{    
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
echo "<center><table width=400 border=1>";
echo "<tr><td><b> Course Name : </b></td><td>". $rows["c"]."</td></tr>
<tr><td><b> Lecturer Name : </b></td><td>". $rows["l"]."</td></tr>
<tr><td><b> Time : </b></td>"

    $qry2="SELECT time FROM courses WHERE courses.course='".$rows['c']."' and courses.lecturer='".$rows['l']."'";
    $results2=mysql_query($qry2);
    if($results2)
    {
    while($rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($results2))
    {
    echo"<td>".$rows2['time']."</td>";
    }
    }
    echo"</tr>";
}
echo "</center></table><br>"
}
else {echo "<center>not available</center>";}
}
```

And this should done it. You have to define table outside of loop, that's why you had for each row separated table.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Updated my first SQL statement, hope it works proper now.

Comment: Same issue, Same Output. I hope you can help more, you're my last hope, you're my hero.

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO! <3 Thanks man :) even though. you should've put echo "<center><table width=400 border=1>"; inside the while loop.

Comment: Also, you know how to use colspan for the tables that has multiple "times"?

Comment: Fixed while loop. I'm not sure if i know what you ask for. If you search that problem you will find several solutions.

Comment: I discovered the solution by myself


$num = mysql_num_rows($results);
.
.
.
<td colspan=".$num.">

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this  




 $qry="SELECT * FROM courses";
        $results=mysql_query($qry);
        $table = '<table width=400 border=1><thead><tr><th>Course Name</th><th>Lecturer Name</th><th>Time</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
        if($results)
        {
        if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0)
        {
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results))
        {

         $table .= '<tr>'
                   . '<td>' .$rows["course"]. '</td>'
                   . '<td>'  .$rows["lecturer"]. '</td>'
                   . '<td>' .  $rows["time"] . '</td>'
                   . '<tr>';


        }
        }
        else {echo "<tr><td>Data not available</td></tr>";}
        }

$table .= '</tbody>'
       . '</table>';
```

Comment: It gave me a blank page. But thank you so much for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL:

```
<?php
$qry = "SELECT DISTINCT lecturer, course, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(time) FROM lectures WHERE lecturer = L.lecturer) 
AS times FROM lectures L";
$results=mysql_query($qry);
if($results)
{
if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0)
{
?>
<table>
<?php
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
echo "<tr><td><b> Course Name : </b></td><td>". $rows["course"]."</td>
<td><b> Lecturer Name : </b></td><td>". $rows["lecturer"]."</td>
<td><b> Times : </b></td><td>". $rows["times"]."</td></tr>";
}
}
else {echo "<center>not available</center>";}
}
?>
</table>
```

It will output:

```
 lecturer   course  times   
John        CSS           2015-10-15 05:14:00,2015-10-16 09:21:18,2015-10-23 07:15:15
Ben     HTML    2015-10-23 07:19:19,2015-10-30 09:17:18
```

Comment: It gave me a blank page. But thank you so much for the help anyways.